# Inactive subwindows in PyQt4

Tags: python, pyqt4

I have been struggling with a problem recently and I cannot get around it. I have a PyQt `QMainWindow` which contains a subwindow :

[image]

As you can figure out, clicking on the GO! button will open a number of subwindows specified by the number in the `QLineEdit` :

[image]

And clicking on the `QCheckBox` inside each subwindow should display a text.

The problem is that this works only for the last spawned subwindow. The others appear to be inactive.
Is their a way to make them active?

Please find my code below:

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui
import mainWin
import subWin
import sys

class MainWindowGui():
    def __init__(self):
        self.w = QtGui.QMainWindow()
        self.MainWindow = myWinCls(self)
        self.MainWindow.setupUi(self.w)
        self.w.showMaximized()

class myWinCls(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self)
        self.parent = parent

    def setupUi(self,Widget):
        self.ui = mainWin.Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(Widget)
        self.ui.mdiArea.addSubWindow(self.ui.subwindow)
        self.ui.goBtn.clicked.connect(self.show_wins)

    def show_wins(self):
        N = int(self.ui.nbrEdit.text())
        for self.k in xrange(N):
            self.show_subwins()

    def show_subwins(self):
        self.win = QtGui.QWidget()
        self.child_window = showSubWinCls(self)
        self.child_window.setupUi(self.win)
        self.subwin = self.ui.mdiArea.addSubWindow(self.win)
        self.win.setWindowTitle("Subwin " + str(self.k))
        self.subwin.show()

class showSubWinCls(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self)
        self.parent = parent

    def setupUi(self, Widget):
        self.ui = subWin.Ui_Form()
        self.ui.setupUi(Widget)
        self.ui.checkBox.clicked.connect(self.show_msg)

    def show_msg(self):
        if self.ui.checkBox.isChecked():
            self.ui.lineEdit.setText("Yiiiiiihaaaaaa !!!")
        else:
            self.ui.lineEdit.setText("")
        
def main():
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setStyle(QtGui.QStyleFactory.create('WindowsVista'))
    ex = MainWindowGui()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I am sure this problem is somehow a classic trick but despite searching for some time now, I cannot figure it out.
Thanks for your help!

Comment: Have you tried to debbug to check the value of `self.ui.checkBox.isChecked` for each sub window?

Comment: Yes. No problem from this point of view...

Comment: Someone added an answer minutes ago and deleted it. Too bad cause the solution proposed seems to work...

Comment: Well, I'll posted it back. I just can't reproduce the behaviour so I'm not sure my answer is right.

Comment: I'm not familiar with ui and setupUi, so I tried to reproduce your problem with simple widgets with buttons. If I try to create several `QWidget` with `self.child_window=myWidget()`, it only shows one. And if try with `QDialog`, it create several that all work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problematic part:

```
def show_wins(self):
    N = int(self.ui.nbrEdit.text())
    for self.k in xrange(N):
        self.show_subwins()

def show_subwins(self):
    self.win = QtGui.QWidget()
    self.child_window = showSubWinCls(self) #erase refererence to previous one
    self.child_window.setupUi(self.win)
    self.subwin = self.ui.mdiArea.addSubWindow(self.win)
    self.win.setWindowTitle("Subwin " + str(self.k))
    self.subwin.show()
```

You are only keeping reference to one subwindow in `self.child_window`, the last window openned.

In `show_wins`, you call `show_subwin` N time. Each time, you redefine `self.child_window` as a new instance of the class `showSubWinCls`. You lose the reference to the previous one.

You need to keep a reference to all the windows, otherwise signals and slots won't work. You can do something like this:

```
class myWinCls(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self)
        self.parent = parent
        self.subWindowList=[]

    def show_subwins(self):
        ...
        child_window = showSubWinCls(self)
        child_window.setupUi(self.win)
        self.subWindowList.append(child_window)
```

Comment: This works well. But I am not sure why... I understand that in my example, the reference to the previous window is lost and in yours it's not. But I don't get why adding this is enough. With this code, I now have a reference of the windows that I created but how do Python know that a particular window is clicked, without any kind of "mouse click detection"?

Comment: There is actually "mouse click detection". How would the GUI know you clicked on a button and not on an empty space otherwise ? It's just more low-level.